# Как получить координаты пользователя?

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Как получить геопозицию пользователя в виде YMKPoint (чтобы можно было вытащить координаты)
В примере https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo есть реализация определения геопозиции, но там просто ставится маркер на позиции пользователя, а самой позиции в виде точки нет.

Comment: Пока сделал используя стандартный фреймворк CoreLocation, но хотелось бы реализовать средствами Яндекса, так как мой проект - это диплом про сравнение карт (в том числе от Яндекс)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно подключиться к YMKMapCameraListener и снимать координаты с cameraPosition.target

Посмотрите пример в моем репозитории: https://github.com/varton86/YandexMapTest